# построить прямоугольник испольуя обьекты

Tags: javascript, ооп

как построить прямоугольник используя конструктор, вроде всё написал но непойму где ошибка.

```js
function ready() {

  function Rectangle(w, h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
  }

  Rectangle.prototype.width = function() {
    return this.width * 2;
  }

  Rectangle.prototype.height = function() {
    return this.height * 2;
  }

  var rectOne = new Rectangle(300, 200);
  var test = document.getElementById("test");

  test.style.background = "red";
  test.style.width = rectOne.width() + "px";
  test.style.height = rectOne.height() + "px";

};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```html
<div id=test></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда говоришь "У меня не работает, помогите!", было бы неплохо писать что говорит то, что не работает (сообщение об ошибке).

У Вас есть свойства `width` и `height`.
В прототипе есть функции с такими же именами.

Свойства/методы сначала ищутся в объекте и, если они не найдены локально, только тогда в цепочке прототипов.
Тут же сразу натыкаемся на `width`, который свойство и дальше искать никто ничего не будет.
Замените названия методов на `getWidth`, например.

Comment: спасибо, исправил, заработало